# circuitikz and rotatebox: How to center a label at a component?

Tags: circuitikz

I want to rotate the label of a resistor by 90°, but the alignment is off. How can I use a `rotatebox` and vertically center the rotated label at the resistor symbol?

MWE result vs. what I want to achieve:
[image: the mwe result][image: my desired result]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[european, straightvoltages,americanvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[R={\rotatebox{90}{$R=\SI{50}{\ohm}$}}] (0,2);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! @zarko answer is the right one (as ever). But notice that `straightvoltage` and `americanvoltages` are conflicting options; in this case, `americanvoltages` always wins (independently from the order in which you give them, by the way).

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[european, 
            straightvoltages, americanvoltages,
            siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{label/align = rotate}
\draw (0,0) to[R, l=50<\ohm>] (0,2);
    \end{circuitikz}

    \begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[R, l=50<\ohm>, label/align = rotate] (0,2);
    \end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For details see package documentation, subsection **5.1.3 Labels and annotation orientation**, page 174 -- 175.

Comment: Thank you, now the label is centered! Is there any way to rotate the label by 180 degrees?

Comment: @MulticolMetallurgist,  of course: use `a` instead of `l` and change direction of drawing. BTW, answer gives what you ask in question. New problem, please ask new question.